# Stop wrapping in the middle of words?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, word-wrap

Has anHas anyone had the issue in MS Powerpoint 2010 where text boxes wrap text in the middle of words regardless of turning "Wrap text in the middle of Latin text" off in the Home>Paragraph>More>Asian Typography tab?

Regardless of changing the Asian Typography settings, lines still wrap in the middle of words.

[image]

Comment: Your example (nonsense text fully justified) may simply be an edge case where the justification algorithm fails. Do you have an example with more normal text and possibly with and without justification enabled? Try typing =Lorem() into a blank text box to get some quick text that more or less follows English word length distribution

Comment: Is there any chance that your spaces are non-breaking spaces?

Comment: Apparently you're not checking for replies, but in case you see this, try posting your example file on the web and reply here with a link to it so others can have a look at it.